# Capturing last location's object in a variable?

Tags: game-maker, gml

Right now I've got about a 10x10 grid of squares that the player can move 1 square at a time on.
When they hop to a square, I need an animation to play based on the sprite_index of the square they're jumping to and the one they just came from.
I've got the "jumping to" one sorted out.
in a collision event between the player and the square (other here being the square):

```
with(other){
if sprite_index = sGreenH {
instance_create(x,y,oGreenPlayerAni)
```

(also is there a better way to do the above? instead of spawning it ontop of what's there can I delete it/replace it THEN put something?)

So now I'm trying to get an animation to play from the square the character is leaving. I can do that with the player collision w/ square :

```
xx = xprevious and yy = yprevious 
instance_create(xx,yy, someanimation)
```

problem there is that I can't customize which animation plays. There are 4 possible colors of animations to use for 4 diff color squares.
so I tried with the collision event in my square with the player making a variable like

```
if sprite_index = sGreen {
global.previousColor = 1
```

for each of my colors. and then in my player's collision event with the square again I have

```
if global.previousColor = 1 {
instance_create(xx,yy, oGreenHollowAni)
```

And then I get an error when I move.

Code square colliding with player (player on a square) : http://puu.sh/n9zCY/2f226b6d3c.png

Code player colliding with square : http://puu.sh/n9zK6/deac1a09f5.png

Error : http://puu.sh/n9zPj/ea84a9a943.png

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question right. As far as I can see, you do always create a new instance when the player is moving?

If so, that is not good. When you create your 10x10 grid of squares I guess you create an array, in which you put the information which color square gets displayed, fe. array[x][y] = color.green ... you could then create an enum an define green = 1, blue = 2 ...
This array would be a global one.
From the player class you then check on which square you are currently and if you move you check on which square you will be. With these informations you can define the animation.

let me know if this was what you meant.

eric